# SharePoint Online: Tags are not linked to their respective documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, tagging

I have tagged a few documents (via Tags and Notes).  I can see the tags in the Tag Cloud but if I click on a tag, the results do not include the recently tagged documents (tagged yesterday).  How long is the delay between tagging a document and it showing up when I click the tag on the Tag Cloud?

Comment: I'm curious. How did you use Tags and Notes on documents and not the list?

Comment: If you click on a list item, and select 'Items' from the Ribbon, you can see 'Tags & Notes'.  You can put Tags and Notes on the individual item from there.  Notice that if you click on more than one item, the 'Tags & Notes' button becomes disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a new tag in tags & notes does as you say end up in the tag cloud right away. You can see the tag, and clicking it gives this image (except the tagged item).

[image]

You have to wait for the search crawl to crawl (and index) the document, before it'll be visible in the tag page. You canät control crawl timer setting, but be aware of that crawling is usually performed every hour. Waiting to 2 minutes past the full hour gave me the above result.

If you're document doesn't show you should [contact support](https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Support/SupportOverview.aspx) from Office 365 Admin Center.